# Is it possible to get referenced element ie. this.$ref inside dateClick function in fullCalendar?

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar-5

I am using vuejs for this project. In FullCalendar(v5.3.0), I've been trying to get the timeGridDay when a particular date is clicked in month view (default view) with the selected date being the day to be shown.

I used ref to reference to FullCalendar component. (Only relevant parts are shown here)

```
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="calendar-holder col-10 section">
      <FullCalendar ref="fullcalendar" :options="options" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And then I tried to use dateClick method to get to the timeGridDay view when a date is clicked.

```
data(){
  return {
    calendarApi: null,
    options: {
      plugins: [ 
        dayGridPlugin,
        timeGridPlugin,
        interactionPlugin,
        listPlugin 
      ],
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      dateClick: function(info) {
        if(confirm('View Schedule?')){
          let calendarApi = this.$ref.fullcalendar.getApi();
          calendarApi.fullCalendar('changeView', 'timeGridDay', info.date);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which didn't work. When I checked the console it said

> TypeError: this.$ref is undefined

but it wasn't undefined when I tried the same code inside mounted hook (initializing calendarApi within data)

```
mounted(){
  this.calendarApi = this.$refs.fullcalendar.getApi();
  console.log(this.calendarApi)
}
```

which returned an object. But I couldn't fetch that calendarApi object inside dateClick method. I tried:

```
dateClick: function(info) {
  if(confirm('View Schedule?')){
    this.calendarApi.fullCalendar('changeView', 'timeGridDay', info.date);
  }
}
```

didn't work. console gave this error:

> TypeError: this.calendarApi is undefined

Is there any way I can get around this problem? I tried to get the calendarApi object from another method as well, but the console said the method is not defined. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `this.$ref` should be `this.$refs`. And `dateClick: function(info) {}` should be `dateClick(info) {}`.

Comment: @tony19 Still the same problem. "this.$refs is undefined"

Comment: Try an arrow function: `dateClick: (info) => {}`

Comment: @tony19 Yeah. we're getting somewhere. Now, its saying calendarApi.fullCalendar is not a function

Comment: @tony19 Thanks for your help. I've solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by changing the dateClick funtion to:

```
          dateClick: (info) => {
            if(confirm('View Schedule?')){
              let calendarApi = this.$refs.fullcalendar.getApi();
              calendarApi.changeView('timeGridDay', info.date);
            }
          }
```

You can find more on this link: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-changeView